# Create a symmetric positive definite matrix (but not diagonal) with eigenvalues $1, 2, 4$ - how to approach this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Trace of the matrix is obviously $7$ and determinant $8$, a $3\times3$ matrix should be easiest to construct, but where to go from here? Any brute force method simply won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Choose an appropriate orthogonal matrix $M$ and take$$M^T.\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}.M.$$

Comment: How does one construct a random orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Take a vector $u$ with norm $1$. Then a vector $v$ orthogonal to $u$, also with norm $1$. Now, take the matrix $M$ such that the entries of its first column are the coordinates of $u$, the entries of its second column are the coordinates of $v$, and the entries of its third column are the coordinates of $u\times v$.

Comment: Why does that method work?

Comment: Because then the columns of your matrix will be vectors with norm $1$ which will be orthogonal to each other. And a matrix is orthogonal if and only if this condition holds.

Answer (score 6):

Why not pick any orthogonal transformation matrix $P$ and easily construct its inverse $P^T = P^{-1}$, with your matrix being $A = PDP^T$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues?

Comment: What is orthogonal transformation matrix?How do you construct such random matrix?

Comment: @user3711671 Why not Google it or use [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation)?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this block-diagonal matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac32 & -\frac12 & 0 \\ -\frac12 & \frac32 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$